# Javascript preloader doesn't load properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, preloader

I have a page where multiple images are preloaded so that changing images using Javascript will go without any loading time or flickering. For this I have a Javascript preloader. It works great in Opera, Safari, Chrome and Explorer and once the page is loaded, you can change images without any flickering or loading time. In Firefox however, it seems to be working but there is a flickering between each of the images. When having passed through all of them once, the flickering between each image disappear when going over them again. I interpret this as the preloader not properly loading the images into the cache of Firefox. My separate preloading script looks like this:

```
<!--
function loadImages()
{
if(document.images)
{
    for(i=0; i<imageArray.length; i++)
    {
        var toLoad = new Image();
        toLoad.src = imageArray[i];
    }
}
} 
-->
```

This is loaded from the head section of the document, first a reference to the external script, then a function to add upp images into the array and then finally called via function loadImages().

You can see it here: http://www.siroccomosaique.se/SLUTTEST/galleri_.cls

If you use Firefox, you will see a really short flickering between the images the first time you scroll through them.

Answer (score 0):

You drop the references to your new images, so they get garbage collected before the load ever finishes.  Put them in an array instead?

Comment: You mean by using the same variable in the loading script or do you mean in the code on the page... I don't think I understand :) Also, what is weird is it works perfectly when I use the same script with smaller images, then even Firefox scrolls through them withoutflickering...

Comment: @fast-reflexes Right now you create each image, store it in a local variable, then start its load.  But when loadImages() returns toLoad goes out of scope and nothing is keeping those images garbage-collected at that point.  If the images are large, they won't fit in the browser's image cache and will get evicted once the HTMLImageElements are GCed.  So what you want to do is to create a global array and store your HTMLImageElements in there.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not being on a higher level but you mean by putting the images in an array with Image types in, and preloading them the way I do now will solve the problem? Basically so that it works like now but they don't get garbage collected before they are to be shown? In case I got that right, can I still store them as Image types or do I have to store them as HTMLImageElements (I don't really know when to use this type but I guess that I can look into it if that's what I need to use for some reason). Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Ah, I think I got it, the actual images must be in an array that is global, I'll try it and get back, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I created a global arraylist to which I inside the loop every time pushed the image that toLoad holds on to at the moment but it didn't remove the flickering between images :( Is it crucial to use an array or would an arraylist be as good? Now I got two global arraylists, one holds the urls to the images and one holds the actual Image objects... Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for messing up all the time, I'm of course using Arrays, and no Arraylists and it's still causing flickering between images the first time around but not the second. No errors in the console.

Comment: Ok, the problem is not with the preloading, it's with the way the images are swapped. I do this by changing background image in CSS (via Javascript), if I use an HTML IMG and change the source of it, then it works without flickering so I need to find out why changing background images in CSS causes flickering. I will start a new thread for that so thanks again for trying to help out :)

Comment: Ah, if you're using background images your problem is probably async decoding, not lack of preloading....

Comment: Yeah! Just to finish up: I first changed images by using Javascript to change the background of a tablecell. I now instead show the images in a IMG tag and use Javascript to change the source of that. This causes less flickering in Firefox even though some of it remains because Firefox's rendering engine seems to be of less high quality than those in the other browsers where it's all handled neatly. All in all, perhaps having Javascript accessing CSS causes more flickering than the other method, I don't know. Thanks anyways for input!

Comment: @fast-reflexes There shouldn't be any flickering when changing the src of an `<img>`.  If you're seeing it, can you please point me to the page where you see it?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's enough to call it flickering but if you go to http://www.siroccomosaique.se/SLUTTEST/galleri_.cls and change images a lot and fast you will sometimes catch the rendering of the new image going over the screen causing a very slight flickering.. This only occurs in FF but I think I'll have to live with that. Fun thing tho is that the others handle this better, especially Chrome and Safari. They are soo fast and neat when swapping images like in this example...

Comment: @fast-reflexes I definitely don't see any flickering there...  Which Firefox version are you using?  Do you see the problem in safe mode?

Comment: I run v. 8.0 and in safemode the slight flickering disappears... What is that about?

Comment: Safe mode does a few things: it disables all your extensions, disables the JS jits, and may disable hardware acceleration.  I doubt the JS bit has anything to do with what you're seeing.  You can try disabling hardware acceleration in normal mode by unchecking Options (or Preferences on Mac or Linux) > Advanced > "Use hardware acceleration when available" and then restarting the browser.  And if you have any interesting extensions, you can try leaving hardware acceleration on and disabling the extensions to see if any of those cause the problem.